# How to echo this json data with their object value?

Tags: php, json

```
{  
   "Content":{  
      "App":null,
      "CompleteFile":null,
      "CompleteFile1":null,
      "DeliveryCharge":"hdDeliveryCharge",
      "ErrorCode":"ErrorCode",
      "ErrorText":"ErrorText",
      "HomeAddress":"hdHomeAddress",
      "IntimationStatus":null,
      "LabOrderNumber":"1",
      "LoginType":null,
      "OrderStatus":null,
      "PaymentCompleteUrl":"",
      "PaymentStartUrl":"",
      "ProfileFile":"",
      "Quuid":null,
      "StoreCount":null,
      "StoreSrNo":null,
      "TransactionId":"TransactionId",
      "UserLat":null,
      "UserLong":null,
      "VersionNumber":null,
      "hdValue":"hdValue"
   },
   "FtpDetail":{  
      "Folder":"FujiFilmIMP",
      "IPAddress":"66.7.149.132",
      "Password":"ox@2017DG",
      "Port":"21",
      "UserName":"oxstudio"
   },
   "Head":{  
      "ErrorCode":"1",
      "ErrorText":"Login success",
      "ErrorValue":null
   },
   "ShippingDetails":null,
   "StoreDetails":null,
   "UserDetails":{  
      "Address":"mira road",
      "City":"mumbai",
      "CountryId":"356",
      "Email":"mamender@dgflick.in",
      "Mobile":"8626065289",
      "Name":"Mamender",
      "Password":"123",
      "PinCode":"400001",
      "StateId":"1575",
      "UserMasterId":"7462"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hopefully those FTP details don't actually work - if they do, please change them on your server immediately.

Comment: Which field is the "object value"?

Answer (score -1):

You need to covert it to an array and then you can loop over the array.

To convert to an array do this assuming your json is in a variable called `$json`

```
$array = json_decode($json);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with it as you would any other array.

Answer (score -1):

Working example!

```
<?php

$data='{  
   "Content":{  
      "App":null,
      "CompleteFile":null,
      "CompleteFile1":null,
      "DeliveryCharge":"hdDeliveryCharge",
      "ErrorCode":"ErrorCode",
      "ErrorText":"ErrorText",
      "HomeAddress":"hdHomeAddress",
      "IntimationStatus":null,
      "LabOrderNumber":"1",
      "LoginType":null,
      "OrderStatus":null,
      "PaymentCompleteUrl":"",
      "PaymentStartUrl":"",
      "ProfileFile":"",
      "Quuid":null,
      "StoreCount":null,
      "StoreSrNo":null,
      "TransactionId":"TransactionId",
      "UserLat":null,
      "UserLong":null,
      "VersionNumber":null,
      "hdValue":"hdValue"
    },
   "FtpDetail":{  
      "Folder":"FujiFilmIMP",
      "IPAddress":"66.7.149.132",
      "Password":"ox@2017DG",
      "Port":"21",
      "UserName":"oxstudio"
   },
  "Head":{  
     "ErrorCode":"1",
     "ErrorText":"Login success",
     "ErrorValue":null
   },
  "ShippingDetails":null,
  "StoreDetails":null,
  "UserDetails":{  
      "Address":"mira road",
      "City":"mumbai",
      "CountryId":"356",
      "Email":"mamender@dgflick.in",
      "Mobile":"8626065289",
      "Name":"Mamender",
      "Password":"123",
      "PinCode":"400001",
      "StateId":"1575",
      "UserMasterId":"7462"
   }
 }';

$dataDecoded = json_decode($data);

?>

<pre>
    <!-- View Ftp detail-->
    <?php print_r($dataDecoded->FtpDetail);?>

    <!--View User Ftp detail Ip adress, will display: 66.7.149.132-->
    <?php echo $dataDecoded->FtpDetail->IPAddress ?>

    <!--View User UserDeatails Email, will display:mamender@dgflick.in-->
    <?php echo $dataDecoded->UserDetails->Email ?>
</pre>
```